# Differences between writing/reading binary/text in c

Tags: c, sockets, binaryfiles

I'm working on a client/server program where the client sends/receives files. The files may be text files or binary files. However, I am not sure what changes I need to make, if any, to accommodate for either file type. Basically I am looking to read/write to a file on the server side without caring what type of file it is, I would like to be able to do so without checking what type of file it was. Would code like this work? Why or why not?

Server snippet:

```
//CREATING/WRITING TO A FILE
//we are ready to begin reading data from the client, and storing it 
int fd = open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
while(nbytes < bytes)
{
    //only read the neccessary # of bytes: the remaining bytes vs max buffer size
    int min_buffer = (bytes - nbytes) < BUFFER_SIZE ? (bytes - nbytes) : BUFFER_SIZE;
    length = recv( client->client_socket, contents, min_buffer, 0);

    if(fd < 0) //the fd is bad, but we need to continue reading bytes anyway
    {
        nbytes += length;
        continue;
    }

    if(length <= 0)
        break;//string empty or error occurred...this error means the client closed?

    if(write(fd, contents, min_buffer) != min_buffer)
    {
        //printf("There was an error writing to the file.\n");
    }
    else
    {       
        nbytes += length;
    }
}


//READING A STORED FILE AND SENDING THE DATA TO CLIENT
int fd = open(pathname, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if(fd >= 0)
{
    while(bytes > 0)
    {
        bytes = read(fd, buffer,  BUFFER_SIZE );

        if(bytes > 0)//we have read some bytes
        {
            //send the client the data
            write(client->client_socket, buffer, bytes);
        }
        else if(bytes < 0)
        {
            //some error occured
            write( client->client_socket, "ERROR: Could not read\n", 22);   
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So if the client sends a binary file vs a text file, would this code cause issues? (We can assume the client knows what type of file to expect.)

Note: Another confusing detail about this is that there are tutorials for writing/reading binary files in c that didn't seem to have any real differences over regular files, which is what lead me here.

Comment: Just do everything with "binary" files. Text files today are just binary files with a little bit special treatment when opened in text mode in Windows; you can read/write them without any problems in binary mode too.

Comment: @deviantfan But what is the difference between 'binary' and 'text' mode (in terms of this code I mean, not by definition)? Does this code use binary mode? How do I switch to it if not?

Comment: It looks like your programming for Linux (only)? Then there isn´t a technical difference between binary and text files, there are just files. If your code works, it will work with other files too. Windows does some strange thing with line breaks in text file mode and MS writes it´s documentation as if there were some fundamental difference between binary/text, but other than the line break thing in Windows, it´s completely the same.

Comment: Addition: If you use standard C `fopen` and `fclose` instead of Linux-specific `open` etc., you can specify to open a file in binary or text mode. This is because fopen should work on Windows too, but what you choose in fopen on Linux doesn´t change anything (which can be verified by reading the source code)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Linux only here. And what a lovely answer, since I don't have to make any major changes for once. Please post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do everything with "binary" files. Linux has no difference between "text" and "binary" in a file on OS level, there are just files with bytes in it. Ie. expect that a file contains every possible byte value, and don´t write different code for different kinds of content.

There is a difference in Windows: Text mode in Windows means that a line break (`\n`) in the program gets converted to/from `\r\n` when writing to / reading from a file. The written text file read in binary mode will contain this two bytes instead of the original `\n` and vice-versa. (Additionally, MS isn´t very clear in the documentation that this is the only difference, it can confuse beginners easily.)

If you use standard C `fopen` and `fclose` instead of Linux-specific `open` etc., you can specify to open a file in binary or text mode (on Linux too). This is because code with fopen should work on Windows and Linux without any OS-specific changes; but what you choose in fopen doesn´t matter when running on Linux (which can be verified by reading the source code of fopen etc.)

And about the sockets:
Linux: No difference (again)
Windows: No difference too. There are just bytes, and no strange line break conversions.

Answer (score -1):

I tore my hair out for a day over a binary/text file issue. I was outputting binary data into "files" (apparently text files ... after years and years of C I'd always thought a file was a file) and kept getting spurious characters inserted into the output. I went so far as to download a new compiler but had the same problem. The issue? When I output hex A using any of the family of fprint statements, hex D was being inserted. Yes, line feed  characters -- A -- were being replaced by carriage return/line feed -- DA. It's a legacy "end of line" issue based on how different systems have developed. The tough part of finding the problem was realizing A was being interpreted as more than just a binary field, but actually being recognized as a line feed.