# File I/O produces different results on different OS. Why?

Tags: c, linux, windows, io

```
// Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file

    uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];
    int16_t buffer = malloc(sizeof(int16_t));


    fread(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);


    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file
    while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
    {
       buffer*=factor;
       fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }



    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

The above code when run on a Linux machine, correctly outputs a audio file that is exactly the same size as the input file (352KB). But when run on a Windows machine, this code outputs an audio file that is only 5KB.

```
while(fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))
{
   buffer*=factor;
   fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
}
```

The above while loop runs only 2119 on the Windows machine while running 17600 times on the Linux.

Any reason for the above behaviour?

I am aware that on different systems data types can vary in size but does it have any relevance here?

Comment: Check `feof` and `ferror` to determine why `fread` is not reading anymore. Also open files as binary (`"rb"`, `"wb"`)

Comment: Opening the files as binary worked.

Comment: Any reason why this only happens on Windows? While on Linux I can just open them as 'r' and 'w'?

Comment: Windows and Linux handle text and binary files differently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966715/differences-between-writing-reading-binary-text-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Streams opened in text mode may stop at a byte with the value `0x1A`.

You should use binary mode to deal with binary files.

To open files in binary mode, add `b` to the mode string for `fopen()` like:

```c
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
```