# How can i read a binary file of integers?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

Im new to c and im trying to get an array of integers from a binary file of integers and i don't understand on how to fix my function.

```
int test_read(const char* filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /*fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);
    if((ftell(fp)%4) != 0){ printf("SEG FAULT");return 0;};
    fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET);*/

    int* tab = new_tab(100);
    int k = 0;
    while (fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
        int a=0;
        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(int);i++){
            a = (a<<8|fgetc(fp));
        }
        tab[k]=a;
        k+=1;
    }
    print_tab(tab);
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;

int *new_tab(int size){
    if(size>0) {
        int *tab = malloc((size)*(sizeof(int)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tab[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return tab;
    }
    else{
        printf("erreur");
        return NULL;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    test_read("data/100");
}
```

data/100 contain 100 integers as binary.

and that's return me :

```
 -1114095639  120378042  -173307421  -1962110490  -19512031  -1843036650  86438161  -903216896  1578651565  1947564876  1435467956  2121161697  -817940757  -1854549618  16834356  -486212261  -1182672308  -660020925  -2020002901  640444696  -1  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100
```

I understand that i have an issue on the way im getting integers but i can't get it.
If someone can help me thanks

Comment: sorry if the question has already been answered but i didn't understand those answers.

Comment: The first step is to open the file in bianry mode: `fp = fopen(filename, "rb");`. And then `while (fgetc(fp) != EOF)` is discarding the byte of data read. I suggest using `fread` to read each integer: `while(fread(...))`

Comment: I suggest you begin with a file of two or three integers, not 100. Then you can more easily post data and what you read.

Comment: thanks i will try with less integers but something like that return the same thing without the same adresses.                                                                                        int* tab = new_tab(100);
    for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
        fread(tab,sizeof(int),100,fp);
    }
    print_tab(tab);

Comment: That's assuming you know there will be 100 of them, but you don't need both the 100 loop *and* the 100 items asked of `fread.` You can omit the `k` loop, or read one integer at a time, but not both.

Comment: uuh i really dont get it, so im just supposed to use fread(tab,sizeof(int),100,fp) one time ? but that return me the exact same thing.

Comment: `fread(tab,sizeof(int),100,fp)` reads 100 ints. Without any loops.

Comment: Also really important is how the integers are stored in your file.  Do they appear like "1234567" or are they in raw binary? -- like each int takes exactly 4 bytes, and such.

Comment: @WeatherVane — that reads "up to 100 ints", and it reports how many it did read, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of course, but the 100 seems to be fixed for this example.

Comment: they are in raw binary, ugly to see as a beginner haha.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd highly recommend checking out the man pages for
[fwrite](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) and [fread](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread).  They provide useful information and give
clear examples on usage.  I think they're the functions needed to
make this work.

One should use the binary modes when opening a binary file.  This is
quite important as on Windows there's differing behaviour between
normal read mode and binary read mode (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967071/20586170) for why).
So in particular, `FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");` is the correct
code for this case.

To read an integer from the stream directly (i.e. as binary):

```
int c = 0;
fread(&c, sizeof(c), 1, fp);
```

To read, say, 100 integers:

```
int nums[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
   fread(nums + i, sizeof(nums[0]), 1, fp);
}
```

Another way, which is nice to look at but is certainly not as readable
IMO is:

```
int nums[100];
fread(nums, sizeof(nums[0]), 100, fp);
```

Note that I'm doing *no* error checking.  That's an exercise for the
reader.

(Small note: I'm making the assumption that the binary file of
integers was written by the same computer you're using to read (or at
least the same architecture), which is probably the case. this is to
ensure that the size of integers on your computer is the same as the
file writer's and that the endianness of integers in the binary file
is the same as your computer's: you can get into some weird errors if
this is not true)

Comment: ok i resolved all my issues thanks

Comment: FWIW, Binary and text modes are equivalent on Posix systems (Unix, Linux, etc).  Windows is as usual the odd one out in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example uses `fwrite` to write to a temporary file the  binary representation of the squares of integers 0 to 9.  It then uses `rewind` to return the file position to the beginning and then `fread`s the 10 integers into freshly allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  FILE* f = tmpfile();
  if(f == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to open temp file");
    return 1;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int j = i * i;
    if(1 != fwrite(&j,sizeof(int), 1, f)) {
      perror("Failed to write an int to file");
      return 2;
    }
  }
  rewind(f);
  int* ints = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  if(10 != fread(ints, sizeof(int), 10, f) ){
    perror("Failed to read 10 ints");
    return 3;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", ints[i]);
  }
}
```